# How to copy pose or keyframes to other armature with same bones structure and naming?

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I was wondering, how to copy a pose from armature.001 to armature.002?
Both armature have same bone name and structure.
I hope to reuse  character A's pose for character B.
Is there way?

Answer (score 4):

Copy Pose and Paste Pose

The arrow indicates the icons.  Menu choice is available.

You must be in Pose Mode of both armatures to use the operation.

[image]