# Put Animations from One Rig to Another

Tags: animation, pose-mode, actions

How can I get an animation from one rig to work on another? They are different rigs and have different names (although I can edit the animation text file so bones have the same name). The ordering of parenting is the same.

SURELY there is SOME combination of using 'copy pose', [this script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204974/how-can-i-copy-the-location-and-rotation-of-multiple-bones-of-a-skeleton-and-pas/205173?noredirect=1#comment361554_205173), and blending modes in the NLA that will allow me to do this?

I know this is vague but I'm looking for a process that would work universally, not just in one specific case. I also know it's not easy, I just don't think it should be 'impossible' with the tools we have.

The animations are kept as text files. If I import the animation to 'new', it makes a new rig using the first frame of the animation as the default pose 'rest' position. If I import the animation 'onto' the desired rig (the rig I want the animation to work on) it uses the second rig's rest pose as the first frame of animation, offsetting from that (usually broken) instead of using its own default (which works).

[Video](https://youtu.be/bS1nQM6YIJM)

As you see, there's lots of combinations, more than shown here. For moments like [this](https://youtu.be/bS1nQM6YIJM?t=93) (the 1-frame top track), I can also delete all 'rotation' keyframes or all 'location' keyframes, which also changes things. I have got this to work a couple times, but I don't understand it enough to reliably repeat it.

Comment: I believe this can only be done for rigs that are identical in terms of naming as well as number of bones present in each. Then it's a simple matter of unlinking (or duplicating) the action of the armature you want to copy animation from and linking it to the armature you want to copy the animation to.

Comment: (Link is broken above) This is often aka re-targeting the animation.  In as much as can "try" and do it all via script , it can go spectacularly  wrong. My take would be to make a conversion rig that uses constraints. Have done this for CMU mocap to rigify meta rig. There was a GSoC addon re automating this somewhat.  Albeit on same bones rig, This  example creates a conversion rig from one super weird rest pose to another more sensible one. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72120/create-pose-from-existing-armature